# Angular JS/Firebase - How do I pass value of Google Autocomplete to Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, firebase

I'm using AngularJS/Firebase (AngularFire) & Google Maps API to create a basic travel wishlist.

So far I have the following:

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="setNewEntry(field)">
   <input type="text" googleplace ng-model="field" />
</form>
```

Controller function:

```
$scope.setNewEntry = function(val) {
  ref.child("places").push({
    "location": val
  })
  $scope.field = "";
}
```

Directive: (to bind autocomplete to input)

```
.directive('googleplace', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
       scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0]);
    }
  }
})
```

This all works fine and pushes the value through to my Firebase app. The issue I'm having is with ng-model not picking up the value that Google provides.

Say I type 'nashville' and I get an autocomplete suggestion, I click on it and it fills in the input with 'Nashville, TN, United States' - once I hit enter to submit the form, it pushes through my initial search query 'nashville'.

Any ideas on how I would pass through the final value of the input?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should tie directive var with parent scope, something like scope: { directiveVar: '=' parentScopeVar }

Comment: One note here, you should always use `object.property` style notation with ng-model, since a direct reference could be broken. For example, `data.field` vs `field` in your ng-model and scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not created a variable that whill hold the values of the autocomplete results . There is a simple directive for adding google places autocomplete to a textbox element which is called as ng-Autocomplete.

Please refer to the following code [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/il2J8qOI2Dr7Ik1KHRm8?p=preview) to know more about the code implementation I am talking about.

```
 //create new autocomplete
        //reinitializes on every change of the options provided
        var newAutocomplete = function() {
          scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], opts);
          google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
            scope.$apply(function() {
//              if (scope.details) {
                scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
//              }
              scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
            });
          })
        }
        newAutocomplete()
```

Comment: Thanks @AniV , I will try this out when I get a chance and get back to you.